# Error: Please verify that the correct package name, SHA-1 and SHA-256 are configured in the Firebase Console.Invalid app info in play integrity token

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, android-emulator, google-play-integrity-api

i am building a react-native app and there i want to add phone authentication i have done all the setup for integrating with firebase and i also added sha-1, sha-256 fingerprint in the firebase project and after i have downloaded the updated google-services.json file in the android/app folder and also enabled the play integrity but still i am getting the error.

Error sending OTP: [Error: [auth/app-not-authorized] This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name, SHA-1, and SHA-256 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ Invalid app info in play_integrity_token ]]